# Can't put files into HDFS

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to set up a hadoop multi-node cluster and I'm getting the following problem.
I have one node as master and another one as slave.

It seems that everything is all right because when I execute `{jps}` I get this processes for the master:

```
{
29983 SecondaryNameNode
30596 Jps
29671 NameNode
30142 ResourceManager
}
```

And this ones for the slave:

```
{  
18096 NodeManager  
17847 DataNode  
18197 Jps  
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try `-put` command, I get this error:

> hduser@master:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ ./hdfs dfs -put /home/hduser/Ejemplos/fichero /Ejemplos/
>   14/03/24 12:49:06 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>   14/03/24 12:49:07 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /Ejemplos/fichero.*COPYING* could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.

When I go to the WebUI, there are 0 live nodes and I don't know why!
I can't fix this error and I would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to check the log files of your data node (slave) for errors in your set up. If you run cloudera CDH, you'll find these in /var/log/hadoop-hdfs, otherwise in the directory specified in your config.

The error "could only be replicated to 0 nodes" points to a problem there.

Also make sure that slave and master can connect via ssh with key authentication.

Just a quick question: you did format your namenode?

Comment: The problem was due to the ssh conection! Thanks!

Comment: I am running multinode cluster in centos. I got the same  error, but my datanodes are active and i can also login using ssh to each slave but still can't put files from linux. Plz help me what is wrong.@Erik Schmiegelow

Answer (score 1):

```
File /Ejemplos/fichero.COPYING could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

the above error means, data nodes are either down or unable to properly communicate with namenode. You can check for the configuration which you specified in hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml.

Comment: How do I check if the datanodes are up? with the jps command it seems that the datanode process are running.
The configuration I've used for the hdfs-site.xml is the following:
<property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
   <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>dfs.permissions</name>
     <value>false</value>
 </property>

And this for the core-site.xml:
<property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>
   <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hadoop/tmp</value>
</property>

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and solved it like this:

1. stop hadoop (stop-dfs.sh and stop-yarn.sh)
2. manually delete dfs/namenode and dfs/datanode directories
3. format namenode (hdfs namenode -format)
4. start hadoop (start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh)

There might be other issues like lack of disk space or *slaves* not configured in $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop (this is actually configured to *localhost* by default.)

Comment: I tried this also because sometimes it works, but not in my case.

Answer (score 0):

you are using as

```
./hdfs dfs -put....
```

Try

```
hadoop fs -put LocalFile.name /username/
```

or

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal LocalFile.name /username/
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried those commands too but the same error is reported.